# Ошибка “Invalid floating point operation”

Tags: delphi, информатика

```
function step(var x:Extended; c:integer): extended;
var
  q:Integer; t:Extended;
begin
  t:=x;
  for q:=1 to c do
    x:=t*x;
  step:=x;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  n,c,z: integer; 
  x,s:Extended;
begin
  n:=2;
  s:=x;
  c:=3;
  z:=14;
  x:=StrToInt(edt1.Text);
  while c<z do
  begin
    if n div 2=0 then
      s:=s-step(x,c)/factorial(x)
    else
      s:=s+step(x,c)/factorial(x);
    n:=n+1;
    c:=c+2;
  end;
  edt2.Text:=IntToStr(Round(s));
end;

end.
```

ОШИБКА ТУТ: `s:=s+step(x,c)/factorial(x);` 
ПОМОГИТЕ РЕШИТЬ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА!!

Comment: Трассировка + Отладка.

Comment: `s:=x;` - `x` неинициализированa, следовательно:  `s` - неинициализированa.

Comment: При больших х возможна потеря порядка и прочие неприятности. В зависимости от размерности х выбирают тот или иной метод решения.

Comment: Функция `factorial` в коде не обнаружена

Answer (score 1):

```
...
x:=StrToInt(edt1.Text);
s:=x;
...
```

Comment: теперь тут выдает ошибку     factorial:= factorial(n-1)*n;

Comment: @кристина Отлично! Значит, предыдущую ошибку мы починили :). Можно отмечать ответ галочкой.